# what is a good sequelize workflow?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm currently working with sequelize / sequelizecli with PostgreSQL and expressJS, I create models and migrations via cli then modify them both then run migrate but it's daunting Is there any one who can share with me a good workflow for medium and large projects?